# ORA-02289 sequence doesn't exist in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
INSERT INTO wrkerrorlog (companycode, creationtimestamp, jobid, sno, errorat, remarks)
SELECT p_companycode,
       p_creationtimestamp,
       'ATSC',
       att_sch_seq.nextval,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                         ORDER BY 1),
                    'Fetching Employees',
                    'No Employees are present for the given criteria.'
```

Comment: sequence does not exist in line 2 att_sch_seq.nextval

Comment: Create the sequence.

Comment: Please edit your question, format code, describe what is the problem. Error seems to be quite obvious. Sequence not exist means either it not exist or user which executes code (may be owner of procedure) has no grants to select on sequence. To help you we need to know if sequence exist and who is its owner as well as who is executing code (owner of procedure)